# O que significa 'fobia'?

Tags: significado

Seria "fobia" apenas medo, como em 'islamofobia'; 'medo' do Islã?

Seria 'medo' do que é considerado bom?

Comment: Não, não é a natureza daquilo que causa o medo que o leva a ser chamado de "fobia", mas sim a natureza do próprio medo, que deve ser anormal/não saudável — conforme diz o [dicionário](https://dicionario.priberam.org/fobia): "noção de medo patológico ou aversão a". A [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fobia) caracteriza como "Fobia é um tipo de perturbação da ansiedade caracterizado por medo ou aversão persistente a um objeto ou uma situação.", com o restante do verbete dando mais detalhes.

Comment: Considerando o que é dado nessas fontes óbvias, o que não fica claro? Essa pode ser uma pergunta de psiquiatria, e não de português.

Comment: Renanlinux, interpretei a tua pergunta apenas como “o que significa 'fobia'?”

Comment: Importante procurar primeiro no dicionário  ou completar melhor a pergunta.

Comment: Acham que o título: "Como é a interpretação de 'fobia' segundo estudos da língua portuguesa", fica melhor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No grego antigo, [*φόβος*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%86%CF%8C%CE%B2%CE%BF%CF%82#Ancient_Greek), significava medo alarmante, aterrorizante, mas não necessariamente paralisante — se alguém vir um leão, provavelmente terá um medo aterrorizante e correrá, esse é. No português, veio para a psicologia. Daí, veio o significado **não técnico** de medo forte ou aversão, como «lembre-se: a fobia tem mais de você do que você dela».

Na psicologia, *fobia*, um transtorno de ansiedade, é um medo **irracional** e **intenso** de algo ou uma situação, causando **angústia significativa**, possivelmente interferindo na vida da pessoa, e a pessoa ativamente evita essa situação ou objeto. Ademais, sufixam-se com *-fobia* palavra que descrevam a fobia, como *hidrofobia*, fobia de água, ou *aracnofobia*, fobia de aranhas. Por ser um termo técnico, é complexo, e falar além foge do escopo do site.

Comment: Se entendi bem, é um medo sensível, mas um medo insensível ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: @renanlinux, se quiseres, vê alguns sites confiáveis na Internet. Imagino que este seja confiável, o hospital, dizem que é bom: https://hospitalsantamonica.com.br/saude-mental/fobia/.